Opc UA Expert Value not shown in View
I am experiencing an issue with reading the value from UA Expert. Specifically, the value is not visible in the Data Access View, although it is accessible and clearly displayed in the Attribute tab.
If you have any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and make the value visible in the Data Access View as well, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Is WKCNTR an object?  What happens when you drag it to the middle of the screen (Data Access View)?

This looks more like a server issue. Maybe get in touch with the server developer.

The datatype of the variables is Null. Probably it was returned by the server when the UaExpert was browsing the server address space. Activate the trace in the UaExpert, and you will find the reason for the issue.
UaExpert trace link
Trace.SDKTraceEnabled = true and Trace.SDKTraceLevel = Data

HI. Thanks for the help. Can you take a look from both the screen and the trace log in the following link.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/88aef29227bdea82e7009f83fc5442e320240530093616/563257

The trace log shows:
08:59:31.423Z|7|1D14* Publish data notification contains 1 data values
08:59:31.423Z|7|1D14*   Value[0] CH=1 Value= Status=0x0
The value is Null. It looks like the UaExpert uses the value (Internal method to get the DataType) received in the data notifications to set the DataType in DataAccessView. I would recommend you initialize the variables with some values.

In my code i received
'Object reference not set to an object instance.'  from item.Value.ToString() and
Null from item.Variant.Type.ToString() where item is DataValue object.
Not sure how to fix this
